# export data to csv using hive sql

Tags: hadoop, hive

How to export hive table/select query to csv? I have tried the command below. But it creates the output as multiple files. Any better methods?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/mapr/mapr011/user/output/'
                    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
SELECT fied1,field2,field3 FROM table1
```

Comment: looks like we are not supposed to export to csv ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive creates as many files as many reducers were running. This is fully parallel.
If you want single file then add `order by` to force running on single reducer or try to increase bytes per reducer configuration parameter:

```
SELECT fied1,field2,field3 FROM table1 order by fied1
```

OR

```
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=67108864; --increase accordingly
```

Also you can try to merge files:

```
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=500000000;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=500000000;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
```

Also you can concatenate files using cat after getting them from hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hadoop fs -cat /hdfspath  > some.csv

command and get the output in one file.

If you want Header then you can use SED along with hive.. See this link which discusses various options in exporting Hive to CSV

https://medium.com/@gchandra/best-way-to-export-hive-table-to-csv-file-326063f0f229